# Height 100% Changing with border/padding

Tags: height

I have two divs, which I aligned side by side, inside a container. I want to make both of them height 100%. I do that and it works fine, but after i change the left div's border or padding it seems to alter the height so it's larger than the right div. Is there any idea how to fix this problem?

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

.one {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a good solution for what you want to achieve

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}

.one {
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

.two {
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
```